Request Metrics Showing More Instances than Actual in App Service Request count Metrics
I am using an App Service Plan P1v3 with 3 instances to run app services. I want to check the number of requests each instance is handling. However, when I check the request metrics from the App Service, it shows more instances than we actually have.Image is attached below for reference

Why is the system displaying more instances than we have in reality? Is there an alternative way to accurately check the number of requests each instance is handling?
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Please share more details about the issue.How you have configured Application Insights?
